# Outputing specific variable from text file to console Java

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, text-files

I am trying to output specific variables from a text file to the console. I am able to read and output the entire file to the console by typing the file name but am always getting a null error exception when trying to get the specific variables. I have tried using delimiters, but those have not worked.

Here is the text file "Input1.txt"

```
pace g {
    int x;
    int y;
    {
        rate x;
        rate z;
    }
}
```

I am able to return the text file with no problem but am confused on how to get

```
pace, int, int, rate, rate
```

to print out. Would a delimiter be the correct way to approach this?

Here is working code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Initialize variables
        Scanner keyboard  = new Scanner(System.in);     // Create Scanner object
        // Prompting user for the text file
        System.out.print("Enter the source path to the text file: ");
        String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
        File file = new File(fileName); // Create File object

        // Check if file exists
        if (file.exists()) {
            // Create a Scanner from the file
            Scanner insideFile = new Scanner(file);

            // For each line in the file, read on the line and display it with the line number
            int lineNumber = 0;

            while (insideFile.hasNext()) {
                String line = insideFile.nextLine();    // read the next line

                // Output the line read to the screen for the user
                System.out.println(++lineNumber + ": " + line);
            }
        // Done reading the file
        insideFile.close();
    }
  }
}
```

I know how to format the output but I am lost on how to output specific variables. Besides a delimiter, would a token be another way to approach this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You will have to create your own parser, or use an existing one like [`gson`](https://github.com/google/gson#google-gson).

Comment: Im thinking: make the pace object Serializable and store that in a file instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a parser. But a simple solution is to read the file line by line and use a regular expression to parse each read line.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

If you share a sample of the source file, i can generate a regex parser for you.

Comment: What do you mean by source file? I have given my code up above and the content in the text file. Are either of these what you mean by source file?

Comment: Would you like me to share my GitHub link with you that has the code in it?